# How install python3-poppler-qt5 on my mac

Tags: python, python-3.x, macos, anaconda

I am looking to install this software (https://github.com/alexisflesch/texamator) on my mac.

For that, I install Python, but I also need to install `python3-pyqt5` and `python3-poppler-qt5`.  But I get an error message.

For the first I have:

```
    $ pip install PyQt5
Collecting PyQt5
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/1e/8f/dd8312af6ed44c15419fb14c38b6532eeb765c428f0642e30dc3ef26b6d4/PyQt5-5.14.0-5.14.0-cp35.cp36.cp37.cp38-abi3-macosx_10_6_intel.whl (43.0MB)
     |████████████████████████████████| 43.0MB 172kB/s 
Collecting PyQt5-sip<13,>=12.7 (from PyQt5)
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/ca/77/ac0e8908be37523f0d93b8002641d11cfbc231c3e9dbaa4835f8073b397d/PyQt5_sip-12.7.0-cp37-cp37m-macosx_10_9_x86_64.whl (62kB)
     |████████████████████████████████| 71kB 843kB/s 
ERROR: spyder 3.3.6 requires pyqtwebengine<5.13; python_version >= "3", which is not installed.
ERROR: spyder 3.3.6 has requirement pyqt5<5.13; python_version >= "3", but you'll have pyqt5 5.14.0 which is incompatible.
Installing collected packages: PyQt5-sip, PyQt5
Successfully installed PyQt5-5.14.0 PyQt5-sip-12.7.0
```

It's seem to be ok, and for the second I get:

```
$ pip install python-poppler-qt5
Collecting python-poppler-qt5
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/6a/7d/65a14ece5dd6a1564b576c1ca30b0f5639be64cc55b62b4d2b497159ed43/python-poppler-qt5-0.75.0.tar.gz
Building wheels for collected packages: python-poppler-qt5
  Building wheel for python-poppler-qt5 (setup.py) ... error
  ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
   command: /opt/anaconda3/bin/python -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/private/var/folders/sf/8b0lljnn487_0hth46wr7j8w0000gn/T/pip-install-mfn34q87/python-poppler-qt5/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/private/var/folders/sf/8b0lljnn487_0hth46wr7j8w0000gn/T/pip-install-mfn34q87/python-poppler-qt5/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' bdist_wheel -d /private/var/folders/sf/8b0lljnn487_0hth46wr7j8w0000gn/T/pip-wheel-5y95ji3s --python-tag cp37
       cwd: /private/var/folders/sf/8b0lljnn487_0hth46wr7j8w0000gn/T/pip-install-mfn34q87/python-poppler-qt5/
  Complete output (15 lines):
  Package poppler-qt5 was not found in the pkg-config search path.
  Perhaps you should add the directory containing `poppler-qt5.pc'
  to the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable
  No package 'poppler-qt5' found
  running bdist_wheel
  running build
  running build_ext
  building 'popplerqt5' extension
  Package poppler-qt5 was not found in the pkg-config search path.
  Perhaps you should add the directory containing `poppler-qt5.pc'
  to the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable
  No package 'poppler-qt5' found
  /opt/anaconda3/bin/sip -I /opt/anaconda3/share/sip -t POPPLER_V0_20_0 -c build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7 -b build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/poppler-qt5.sbf -I /opt/anaconda3/share/sip/PyQt5 -n PyQt5.sip -t Qt_5_14_0 -t WS_MACX poppler-qt5.sip
  sip: Usage: sip [-h] [-V] [-a file] [-b file] [-B tag] [-c dir] [-d file] [-D] [-e] [-f] [-g] [-I dir] [-j #] [-k] [-m file] [-o] [-p module] [-P] [-r] [-s suffix] [-t tag] [-w] [-x feature] [-X id:file] [-y file] [-z file] [@file] [file]
  error: command '/opt/anaconda3/bin/sip' failed with exit status 1
  ----------------------------------------
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for python-poppler-qt5
  Running setup.py clean for python-poppler-qt5
Failed to build python-poppler-qt5
Installing collected packages: python-poppler-qt5
  Running setup.py install for python-poppler-qt5 ... error
    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: /opt/anaconda3/bin/python -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/private/var/folders/sf/8b0lljnn487_0hth46wr7j8w0000gn/T/pip-install-mfn34q87/python-poppler-qt5/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/private/var/folders/sf/8b0lljnn487_0hth46wr7j8w0000gn/T/pip-install-mfn34q87/python-poppler-qt5/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record /private/var/folders/sf/8b0lljnn487_0hth46wr7j8w0000gn/T/pip-record-1jvxu2r8/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile
         cwd: /private/var/folders/sf/8b0lljnn487_0hth46wr7j8w0000gn/T/pip-install-mfn34q87/python-poppler-qt5/
    Complete output (15 lines):
    Package poppler-qt5 was not found in the pkg-config search path.
    Perhaps you should add the directory containing `poppler-qt5.pc'
    to the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable
    No package 'poppler-qt5' found
    running install
    running build
    running build_ext
    building 'popplerqt5' extension
    Package poppler-qt5 was not found in the pkg-config search path.
    Perhaps you should add the directory containing `poppler-qt5.pc'
    to the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable
    No package 'poppler-qt5' found
    /opt/anaconda3/bin/sip -I /opt/anaconda3/share/sip -t POPPLER_V0_20_0 -c build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7 -b build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/poppler-qt5.sbf -I /opt/anaconda3/share/sip/PyQt5 -n PyQt5.sip -t Qt_5_14_0 -t WS_MACX poppler-qt5.sip
    sip: Usage: sip [-h] [-V] [-a file] [-b file] [-B tag] [-c dir] [-d file] [-D] [-e] [-f] [-g] [-I dir] [-j #] [-k] [-m file] [-o] [-p module] [-P] [-r] [-s suffix] [-t tag] [-w] [-x feature] [-X id:file] [-y file] [-z file] [@file] [file]
    error: command '/opt/anaconda3/bin/sip' failed with exit status 1
    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: /opt/anaconda3/bin/python -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/private/var/folders/sf/8b0lljnn487_0hth46wr7j8w0000gn/T/pip-install-mfn34q87/python-poppler-qt5/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/private/var/folders/sf/8b0lljnn487_0hth46wr7j8w0000gn/T/pip-install-mfn34q87/python-poppler-qt5/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record /private/var/folders/sf/8b0lljnn487_0hth46wr7j8w0000gn/T/pip-record-1jvxu2r8/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile Check the logs for full command output.
```

I do not understand why and how to correct.

I also did:

```
$ pip search poppler
python-poppler-qt4 (0.24.0)  - A Python binding to Poppler-Qt4
python-poppler-qt5 (0.75.0)  - A Python binding to Poppler-Qt5
pdfparser-si (0.2.6)         - python bindings for poppler
pdfparser-rossum (1.3.3)     - python bindings for poppler
pdflib (0.2.1)               - python bindings for poppler
pypoppler (0.12.2)           - Python bindings for poppler-glib, unofficial
                               branch including bug fixes, and removal of gtk
                               dependencies
```

Usually I use Homebrew to install the different packages.

Comment: Did you manage to fix the issue ?

Comment: How did you originally install Python 3? You seem to have Anaconda; probably [edit] your question with details about this.

Answer (score 0):

Finally, my advice would be to use the Macports package manager to install Python3, pyqt5, and poppler-pyqt5.

```
sudo port install pyqt5
sudo port install python-poppler-qt5
```

I tried with PIP but PIP does not install SIP completely. And with the Homebrew package manager I get other errors that I couldn't fix.